# Tabulator - Layout Options

Tags: tabulator

If I set my table to use the layout "fitDataTable" I get the following

[image]

This is what I expect and find.

However, if I set the layout to "fitDataStretch" keeping everything else the same I get the following

[image]

Its good that it now fits the width how I want, however notice the big gap at the bottom and the way it's not showing all the rows.

Stranger still if I try setting the table height I get the following (redraw() seems to do nothing)

[image]

Notice still it still doesnt show all the data but also the header seems to have stretched

Since the containing element is exactly the same, all I am changing is the layout when creating the table, im struggling to find out why the layout looks broken, I can only assume that when Tabulator creates the table it doesnt like something on the containing element, but if you have any pointers between the differences in how the two layouts work I would apriciate it.

Comment: It is hard to offer you advice without seing how your table is setup. You would be more likely to get a response if you post a link to a JSFiddle or Code Pen that demonstrates the issue

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think I have just found the culprit...certain layouts in Tabulator don't seem to play nice if the containing element has CSS  display:grid.

Comment: Ahh that is down to the way the resize it triggered. There are already issues covering how to deal with that, do a quick search on here and you should find the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain layouts in Tabulator don't seem to play nice if the containing element has CSS display: grid -it was possible for me to change to display: block and everything worked as expected. Also, see the comment from @oli Folkerd